# Macro to Repeatedly Copy to a New Line

Tags: excel, vba, random

This macro copies cell `H19` and pastes it's value in to cell `P13`

How would you rewrite this so that the operation (Copy & Paste) runs 100 times and each time pastes the `H19` Cell in to the next cell down after `P13`

```
Sub Button4_Click()
'
' Button4_Click Macro
'
Range("H19").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("P13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

This is being used to copy the output of a Sum which uses `RAND()` and as such I want to calculate this Sum multiple times using different random numbers and record the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub Button4_Click()

    For i = 1 To 100
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P13").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H19").Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: if P13 was in a different sheet how do you reference that?

Comment: @BenJackson, see my updated answer: change "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" to sheet names, that are true for you